# How fast does fire spread?

Tags: dnd-5e, environmental-hazards

In our latest session my group ran into an awakened tree. We have managed to set it on fire, however there is also a giant spider and some webs in the awakened tree's branches.

How many turns does it take for fire to spread? How soon will the webs and giant spider be affected?

Answer (score 8):

There are no rules for this in 5e. It's entirely up to your DM.